# How does Docker allow portable containers if the Kernel libraries change

Tags: linux, kernel, docker

If my program depends on some function of a kernel library, and that function in turn has a chain of dependencies, how does docker stay small and portable without taking a snapshot of all the kernel libraries (and managing dependency issues at a function rather than library level)?  In other words how does it insulate itself from changes in Kernel libraries from one version to the next, and does it do so at a library or function granlarity?

Also what if my application has a software stack where for example one function is compatible with a future version of kernel library A whereas a second function that uses kernel library A is no longer compatible.  In other words:

function 1&2 both depend on and work with functions in kernel Lib A version 1.0

function 1 works with Lib A version 1.1
function 2 breaks with Lib A version 1.1 (function 2 still needs Lib A version 1.0)

I don't know much about Docker so this is a newbie question.

Answer (score 19):

There is no such thing as a "kernel library". The closest things to what you're describing are:

- `libc`, which is part of the container image, and hence does not change.
- The Linux kernel ABI, which is mostly constant. While some changes are occasionally made to the kernel ABI, this is done as rarely as possible - kernel developers do everything possible to maintain backwards compatibility. Where changes are made, it is most often in components that would not be relevant to applications running in a container (e.g, audio / video output, dynamic device management, etc).

Comment: libc and the Linux kernel are very much intertwined The kernel you're running on was compiled with a specific libc. The libc you have was compiled to only support kernels above a specific version. If you update one without the other you can be in for a world of pain.

Comment: I believe the OP meant the system calls supported by different versions of the kernel. These are highly correlated to libc. So do containers somehow cheat and use the base system's libc? Could you run into trouble if some software attempted to directly invoke a syscall not supported in the base kernel?

Comment: glibc is shipped as a regular file (for example as `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so`) and is hence part of the docker image. It may thus happen that the glibc inside the image is not compatible with the host kernel (see some words on glibc/linux compatibility [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9705/can-new-glibc-versions-be-used-with-an-old-kernel)). A serious problem arises if glibc makes a syscal that the host kernel has not implemented yet. This happened to me with [boost.filesystem](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/issues/164).